# How do I display more than one variable value as the biggest inputed? (C language)

Tags: c

It's for an exam. I have to display which of the 5 cities had the most and the less number of car accidents in a certain time space, based off of the data inputted by the user. I was able to write the code and it works fine.

But what if there are cities with the same number of accidents?

How do I display multiple cities that had the same number of accidents?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
  int accidents, variant, biggest, smallest, biggest_city, smallest_city;

  biggest = 0;
  variant = 1;

  while (variant <= 5) {
    printf("How many accidents happened in city %i? ", variant);
    scanf("%i", &accidents);
    if (accidents > biggest) {
      biggest = accidents;
      biggest_city = variant;
    }
    if (accidents < smallest) {
      smallest = accidents;
      smallest_city = variant;
    }
    variant++;
  }

  printf(
      "\nThe biggest number of accidents is %i and it belongs to city %i\n"
      "The smallest number of accidents is %i and it belongs to city %i\n",
      biggest, biggest_city, smallest, smallest_city);
}
```

Comment: cor_de_rosa, When `smallest=accidents;` executes (the line after `biggest=0;`), what value do you think is in `accidents`?

Comment: None, really. I just wanted to set the smallest number of accidents as being the first value inputed. I've just now realised it is useless. I'm going to edit it from the post.

Comment: The instructions aren't clear when one has a tie; in this case, I would document what happens.

Comment: @cor_de_rosa The usual code idiom to to initialize `biggest` to the least `int` value and `smallest` to the greatest: `biggest = INT_MIN; smallest = INT_MAX;`.

Comment: @cor_de_rosa With code update, the first time `accidents < smallest` executes, what value do you think is in `smallest`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i suggest using "unsigned int" instead of "int", cause you don't need negative numbers of accidents, also it might help with searching for the smallest number of accidents.

You can solve it by adding and array, where you would keep amount of accidents in town, and then go through it to search for the cities, where number of accidents is equal to the biggest.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // You need to remember, that if you initialize your variable 
    // without assigning value to it, it might lead to 
    // Undefined behaviour (Read about it if you don't know about it)
    // Baisicly, your variable might return everything 
    // (from -2147483647 to 2147483647 in your case)
    unsigned int variant = 0, biggest = 0, smallest = 0;
    bool single_city = true;
    
    unsigned int accidents[5] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    
    biggest = 0;
    // Because "smallest " is unsigned int, 0 - 1 would be 
    // equal to 4294967295 (max unsigned int value), not -1
    smallest = -1;
    variant = 1;
    
    
    while (variant <= 5)
    {
        printf("How many accidents happened in city %i? ", variant);
        scanf("%i", &accidents[variant - 1]);
        
        if(accidents[variant - 1] > biggest)
        {
            biggest = accidents[variant - 1];
        }
        if(accidents[variant - 1] < smallest)
        {
            smallest = accidents[variant - 1];
        }
        variant++;
    }
    variant = 1;
    
    printf("\nThe biggest number of accidents is %i and it belongs to city: ", biggest);
    
    while (variant <= 5)
    {
        if(accidents[variant - 1] == biggest)
        {
            printf("%i", variant);
            if (single_city == true)
            {
                single_city == false;
            }
            else 
            {
                printf(", ");
            }
        }
        variant++;
    }
    
    variant = 1;
    single_city = true;
    
    printf("\nThe smallest number of accidents is %i and it belongs to city: ", smallest);
    
    while (variant <= 5)
    {
        if(accidents[variant - 1] == smallest)
        {
            printf("%i", variant);
            if (single_city == true)
            {
                single_city == false;
            }
            else 
            {
                printf(", ");
            }
        }
        variant++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Considering `smallest = -1;` vs. `smallest = UINT_MAX;`, which one do you think better conveys to a reviewer that code is assigning the maximum value to `smallest`?

Comment: Well, in pure C if I'm not mistaken macros UINT_MAX requires additional library (limits.h) in order to work, also, I left a comment, that explains how "0 - 1" is working. And from perspective of a reviewer, it would be nice to see, that person understands, how datatypes work (at least at baisic level). @chux-reinstate-monica